# How to count running balance for passbook statement in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a passbook statement screen where it shows daily transactions with running balance..

I have created a demo for explaining what I want...

I have a dataList that contains three keys ['Month','totalExpense','totalIncome']

and using map, I am creating another new list with 4 keys ['Month','totalExpense','totalIncome','RunningBalance']

I am getting my output properly with my code,

but is there any other way that I can add new key to existing List( I mean to my original dataList) to avoid creating another list

```
List<Map<String,dynamic>> dataList=[
  {
    'Month':'January',
    'totalExpense':3000,
    'totalIncome':8000,
    'Balance':5000,

  },
  {
    'Month':'February',
    'totalExpense':8000,
    'totalIncome':2000,
    'Balance':-6000,

  },
  {
    'Month':'March',
    'totalExpense':2000,
    'totalIncome':8000,
    'Balance':6000,

  },
  {
    'Month':'April',
    'totalExpense':9000,
    'totalIncome':5000,
    'Balance':-4000,

  },

];




void main()
{
  double runBalance=0;
  List<Map<String,dynamic>> answerlist=[];

  answerlist=dataList.map((e) {
    runBalance=runBalance+e['Balance'];

    return {
      'Month':'April',
      'totalExpense':9000,
      'totalIncome':5000,
      'RunningBalance':runBalance,
    };
  }).toList();

  print(answerlist);


}
```

output  like

```
Month.    Inc.  Exp.  Bal  RunBal
January   4000 2000  2000 2000
February. 5000 8000. -3000 -1000
March.    1000 4000 -3000  -4000
```

I tried this one but how to add key in map

```
void main()
{

  double runbalance=0;


  dataList.map((e) {
    runbalance=runbalance+e['Balance'];

    return //add key and apply value runbalance;
  }).toList();


  print(dataList);

}
```

Comment: you want to add runBal to dataList? how to calculate runBal?

Comment: this is what making me confused....

Comment: so is It compulsory to take another list with?

Comment: I mean for example where is January's RunBal come from?

Comment: could you add your current answer?

Comment: actually I have transaction list and from this list I have created a List<Map<String,dynamic>> datalist....January balance is 5000 so first running balance is 5000 and than February balance -6000 so running balance is -1000

Comment: I could not explain u properly...but it is solved...I was not aware how to add key and value pair in map....

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer

```
void main()
{

  double runbalance=0;
  dataList.map((e) {
    runbalance=runbalance+e['Balance'];

    return e['runBalance']=runbalance;
  }).toList();


  print(dataList);

}
```